# How to get specific portion of data from 1D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, copy

I have a regular [NativeArray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.html) of colors. I want to efficiently sample and get a specific portion of data from that array depending on the given rect.

Let's say I have this 5x5 (25 in length) size 1D color array and I need to get data from this rect (x:2, y:1, w:3, h:2) as shown in the below picture

[image]

How can I do that?

If I try to use the function [NativeArray<>.Copy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.Copy.html) it copies from index to length. So if I specify index 7 and 6 length it would copy from 7 to 12, which wouldn't work for me.

Comment: It seems that you want two specific portions. What's stopping you from making the requisite call twice, once for 7-9, and then for 12-14?

Comment: I could do that however I am dealing with much larger images and it would be quite inefficient I think

Comment: I would suggest that you reformat your data in a way that allows you to do this efficiently then.

Comment: If it's a 2d array then store them into a 2d array. Then the matter is about setting the indexes. You know the start point (x,y) then how far to the right (w). Repeat the same for as many lines (y) increasing the y value each time. Put all that in a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NativeArray.Copy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.Copy.html) as you found out can take a start index where the copy should begin and an end index where it should end. Your scenario is more complicated.
You may treat the Native array as a 2D array and use a nested for loop to copy elements from it over to the destination. The Copy method does the same, it is not a magic thing.

You may use following formula to convert 2D x, y indexes to 1D index

```
i = y * width + x
```

Comment: If it helps you, please mark it as answer.